# How to compile images as batch from two layers taken from two directories

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I have two directories with images having identical file names. I would like to take one image from each directory and compile them and flatten. Then repeat as a batch for each filename.

Can I use mogrify in some way? Or do I need to script it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have to script it, but it doesn’t have to be complicated—it can be a one-line shell script. Suppose you have files `fg/001.jpg`, `fg/002.jpg`, …, `bg/001.jpg`, `bg/002.jpg`, … and you want to layer them and put the results in `out`.

Then this one-liner shell script will do what you want:

```
for F in fg/*; do composite "${F}" bg/"${F#fg/}" out/"${F#fg/}"; done
```

The shell variable `F` loops over all files, and the messy `"${F#fg/}"` bit is just shell magic to strip off the directory prefix.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response on this. Much appreciated.